# Does using the Silent Spell metamagic change the action cost for a spell?

Tags: actions, metamagic, spell-components, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e

[Silent Spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=644) costs 1 action, but allows you to waive the spell's verbal component.  Does waiving the verbal component reduce the spell's action cost by 1, thus producing no net change in the number of actions to cast the spell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**  There is no rule that ties the action cost of Cast a Spell to the components of the spell.

Comment: P.303 "A spell description lists the components required to Cast the Spell. For most spells, the number of components is equal to the number of actions you must spend to Cast the Spell."

Comment: Good point.  The correspondence is therefore intentional without being a rule.